# WinForm TokenEdit control with bitwise Enum ([Flags])

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

How to use a DevExpress `TokenEdit` Control with a bitwise enum?

(I was unable to find any comprehensive short documentation on this case. A bit [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17088) and some [there](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/WhatsNew/DXperience/files/14.2.4.bc.xml#autolist8).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the enum

```
[Flags]
public enum BeverageInfoEnum
{
    Water       = 1 << 0,
    HasAlcool   = 1 << 1,
    Wine        = 1 << 2, 
    Soda        = 1 << 3, 
    Warm        = 1 << 4
}
```

The `[Flags]` attribute is mandatory here. Values can be mixed.

The DevExpress TokenEdit has a new feature (starting **14.2.4**) thant handles automatically bitwise enums. Let's say, in your Control/Form you have a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.TokenEdit tokenEditInfo`, you can simply:

```
// can be set in designer mode
this.tokenEditInfo.Properties.EditValueType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.TokenEditValueType.Enum; 

// this is were the magic happens
this.tokenEditInfo.Properties.Tokens.AddEnum(typeof(BeverageInfoEnum), true, true);
```

Then, you can get the value from it (or just use DataBinding on `EditValue`):

```
var b = (BeverageInfoEnum)this.tokenEditInfo.EditValue
```

You'll have all the bitwise values in `b` aggregated. As you expected. Same when setting the value:

```
var b = BeverageInfoEnum.Water | BeverageInfoEnum.Warm;
(BeverageInfoEnum)this.tokenEditInfo.EditValue = b;
```

The `TokenEdit`control will split the bitwise value in two and show the two separated tokens.